# Поправить PHP код вывода отзыва для всех типов записей, а не для одного типа

Tags: php, html, wordpress, синтаксис

Перемещаю кусок PHP кода из сайдбара внутрь записи. Этот кусочек отвечает за вывод последнего отзыва к данной записи.

```
<?php
global $post, $accommodation_price, $date_from, $date_to, $price_decimal_places, $default_currency_symbol, $show_currency_symbol_after, $current_user, $accommodation_obj, $score_out_of_10, $bookyourtravel_review_helper, $bookyourtravel_theme_globals;
$enable_reviews = $bookyourtravel_theme_globals->enable_reviews();
$accommodation_location = $accommodation_obj->get_location(); 
?>
    <?php if ($enable_reviews) { ?>
        <div>
            <?php 
                $all_reviews_query = $bookyourtravel_review_helper->list_reviews($accommodation_obj->get_base_id());
                if ($all_reviews_query->have_posts()) { 
                    while ($all_reviews_query->have_posts()) { 
                    $all_reviews_query->the_post();
                    global $post;   
                    $likes = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'review_likes', true); 
                    $author = get_the_author();
                    ?>
                    <!--testimonials-->
                    <article class="testimonials">
                        <blockquote><?php echo $likes; ?></blockquote>
                        <span class="name"><?php echo $author; ?></span>
                    </article>
                    <!--//testimonials-->
            <?php break; } } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } // $enable_reviews ?>
```

Этот код расположен в отдельном файле темы (review-item.php) и этот код применяется ко всем типам записей (их три: accommodation, cruise, tour). Проблема в том что я вставил этот код выдернув из сайдбара записей accommodation. И для типа записей accommodation работает всё отлично. Но так как в общем файле review-item.php сейчас вставлен код из сайдбара accommodation, на записях cruise и tour выбивается ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста сделать код, что бы он работает и для accommodation и для cruise и для tour. Ниже я прикреплю код из сайдбара cruise:

```
<?php
global $post, $cruise_price, $current_user, $show_currency_symbol_after, $default_currency_symbol, $price_decimal_places, $cruise_obj, $score_out_of_10, $bookyourtravel_theme_globals, $bookyourtravel_review_helper;
$enable_reviews = $bookyourtravel_theme_globals->enable_reviews();
?>
<?php if ($enable_reviews) { ?>
        <div>
            <?php 
            $all_reviews_query = $bookyourtravel_review_helper->list_reviews($cruise_obj->get_base_id());
            if ($all_reviews_query->have_posts()) { 
                while ($all_reviews_query->have_posts()) { 
                    $all_reviews_query->the_post();
                    global $post;   
                    $likes = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'review_likes', true); 
                    $author = get_the_author();
                    ?>
                    <!--testimonials
                    <article class="testimonials">
                        <blockquote><?php echo $likes; ?></blockquote>
                        <span class="name"><?php echo $author; ?></span>
                    </article>
                    //testimonials-->
                    <?php 
                    break; 
                } 
            } ?>
        </div>
```

И для tour:

```
<?php
global $post, $accommodation_price, $date_from, $date_to, $price_decimal_places, $default_currency_symbol, $show_currency_symbol_after, $current_user, $accommodation_obj, $score_out_of_10, $bookyourtravel_review_helper, $bookyourtravel_theme_globals;
$enable_reviews = $bookyourtravel_theme_globals->enable_reviews();
$accommodation_location = $accommodation_obj->get_location(); 
?>
<?php if ($enable_reviews) { ?>
        <div>
            <?php 
            $all_reviews_query = $bookyourtravel_review_helper->list_reviews($tour_obj->get_base_id());
            if ($all_reviews_query->have_posts()) { 
                while ($all_reviews_query->have_posts()) { 
                $all_reviews_query->the_post();
                global $post;   
                $likes = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'review_likes', true); 
                $author = get_the_author();
                ?>
                <!--testimonials
                <article class="testimonials clearfix">
                    <blockquote><?php echo $likes; ?></blockquote>
                    <span class="name"><?php echo $author; ?></span>
                </article>
                <//testimonials-->
                <?php 
                    break; 
                } 
            } ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Надеюсь, вы уже выяснили, что разница в этих трех кусках кода - в параметрах, которые передаются в функцию list_reviews. Больше ничего из приведенного кода понять невозможно. Разбирайтесь с тремя видами переменных _obj. Выясните для начала, чем вызвана ошибка.

Comment: @Ponio Я это понимаю, что в list_reviews. Ошибки то нет по сути. Мне просто нужно прописать в общем коде, что бы не только к accommodation относилась функция, но и к tour и cruise.

Comment: Так вызывайте одну из функций для нахождения $all_reviews_query в зависимости от того, какой файл *_obj задан.

Comment: @Ponio Я логически понимаю как это сделать, но плохо владею PHP, по этому и прошу помощи здесь.

Comment: Посмотрите функцию isset, например. Или вот: $a ?? $b ?? $c The first operand from left to right that exists and is not NULL. NULL if no values are defined and not NULL. Available as of PHP 7. (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: вы используете какие-то плагины в работе или код полностью самописный? Если первое, то было бы неплохо их перечислить

Comment: @alenkins Это не плагины. Это сразу было в шаблоне, который мы покупали на Themeforest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
global $post, $accommodation_price, $date_from, $date_to, 
$price_decimal_places, $default_currency_symbol, 
$show_currency_symbol_after, $current_user, 
$accommodation_obj, $score_out_of_10, $tour_obj, $cruise_obj,
$bookyourtravel_review_helper, $bookyourtravel_theme_globals;


$enable_reviews = $bookyourtravel_theme_globals->enable_reviews();
if (!empty($accommodation_obj)) {

$accommodation_location = $accommodation_obj->get_location(); 
$poly_object = $accommodation_obj;
}
else if(!empty($cruise_obj)){
$poly_object = $cruise_obj;
}
else if(!empty($tour_obj)) {
$poly_object = $tour_obj;
}
?>
    <?php if ($enable_reviews) { ?>
        <div>
            <?php 
                $all_reviews_query = $bookyourtravel_review_helper->list_reviews($poly_object->get_base_id());
                if ($all_reviews_query->have_posts()) { 
                    while ($all_reviews_query->have_posts()) { 
                    $all_reviews_query->the_post();
                    global $post;   
                    $likes = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'review_likes', true); 
                    $author = get_the_author();
                    ?>
                    <!--testimonials-->
                    <article class="testimonials">
                        <blockquote><?php echo $likes; ?></blockquote>
                        <span class="name"><?php echo $author; ?></span>
                    </article>
                    <!--//testimonials-->
            <?php break; } } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } //
```

Comment: Выбивает ошибку 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in' . Я напомню, что код был взят из шаблона записей accommodation, я так понимаю если делать общий, то там не должно быть указано accommodation, а в вашем ответе он присутствует.

Comment: Еще раз попробуйте, запятую забыл

Comment: $bookyourtravel_review_helper, $bookyourtravel_theme_globals; - вот тут, почти в начале

Comment: еще раз попробывали?

Comment: Теперь пишет Fatal error: Call to a member function get_base_id() on a non-object in , на строчке: $all_reviews_query = $bookyourtravel_review_helper->list_reviews($poly__object->get_base_id());

Comment: попробуйте, еще одна опечатка была

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает. Очень помогли